# Chrome's MediaSource woes and DVLOGs

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, video, chromium, media-source

I have fragmented MP4 streams of H.264-encoded video which I'm trying to reconstruct in Chrome using the `MediaSource` API.

For the sake of this discussion, I have two made such streams, both of which play correctly when included as the `src` of a `<video>` tag. However, when fed into `MediaSource`, one of them does not work while the other one does. Looking in `chrome://media-internals`, both streams produce a bunch of `Skipping unrecognized top-level box: mdat` (even though one is clearly playing fine so it cannot possibly have ignored them entirely).

In any case, the one that fails to play get stuck at `kInitPrerolling` without throwing any error. I want to get to the bottom of this, however this is proving difficult as diagnostic messages are printed as `DLOG`s and `DVLOG`s in the Chromium source and these are excluded from Chrome's debug build.

Would someone be able to either:

- Shed some light on why Chrome might be refusing the play the stream; or
- Give some instructions on how I can see the DVLOGs from Chrome's MediaSource pipeline (preferably on OSX). Chrome Canary does not print out DVLOGs, while the Chromium build says H.264 is not supported, so I am assuming that the standard debug-building instructions won't give me an executable with H.264 support.